# Updates versus compile time debugging. How to stop the oddities?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, patch, self-updating

Are we reduced to ClickOnce to manage our application state for our users?

We use our own installer and Visual Patch currently. 
When our users update using our Visual Patch download (we can reproduce this) we get errors from the updated versions which never show up in our dev enviroment.

Since our developer state is not 'updated' with Visual Patch how can we monitor and eventually squash the various System.MethodNotFound, and System.NullReferenceException in our updated versions of our application?

Comment: Can you describe the update sequence in more detail?

Comment: We have a configuration tool which detects our versions. The user downloads a Visual Patch payload and runs it. When the user runs our application and begins the use of it, we run into errors that the same process doesn't yield in our developer environment. When we patch a copy of our application ourselves we obtain those exceptions.

Comment: Sounds like Visual Patch is not patching properly. Have you considered contacting support for Visual Patch?